# bash looping over files while tailing logs

Tags: bash, logs, tail

I'm running a daemon that process files in a specific dir.
I want to process those one by one. so idea is I will copy files 1 by 1 in daemon dir, and tail its log, 2nd file should be copied to daemon dir when log file finishes processing first, i.e, log file stops updating.

how can I achieve that?
say

```
daemon_dir=/var/daemon_dir/
daemon_log_file=/var/daemon/daemon_log
```

and I have 5 files to process i.e, file{1..5}

```
# ls -1
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
```

so my loop should go as is.

```
for file in file{1..5}
do
  cp ${file} ${daemon_dir}
  # daemon sees new file arriving in its dir, & starts processing
  # log is tailed
  tail -f ${daemon_log_file}
  # when log file stops updating say for 1minute or specified time, tail quits
done
```

and loop starts with next file.

Comment: If on Linux, Instead of waiting for a long period of inactivity on the log file, you could wait for a IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE inotify event on the input files.

Comment: Do you need to dump the log on stdout? Or are you just wanting to use tail -f to detect when the daemon has finished with the input file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I want to tail it also, just so I'm aware there're no error in processing.

Comment: Why don't you set up `grep` to look for key phrases that indicate an error, or alternatively set it up to skip lines that are not errors. You can then review the reduced output (if there is any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
for file in file{1..5}; do
  cp -- $file $daemon_dir || exit
  touch -- $daemon_log_file
  while
    ()(($#)) $daemon_log_file(Nmm-1)
  do
    zselect -t 100
  done
done
```

(`zselect -t 100` sleeps for 1 second. Like `sleep 1` except `zselect` is builtin. `tail -f` typically also checks for new input in the file every second (though on Linux some implementations use inotify instead to detect incoming input)).

Above, we use the `mm-1` (`m`odified less than 1 `m`inute ago) glob qualifier to detect when the daemon has finished processing the file.

If on Linux, you could monitor for the `IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE` inotify event on the file instead, assuming the daemon opens the input files only once (and is the only one opening it) and takes enough time to process the file so we have time to setup the watch

```
for file in file{1..5}; do
  cp -- "$file" "$daemon_dir" || exit
  inotifywait -qqe close_nowrite -- "$daemon_dir/$file" 
done
```

For a `tail -f`-based approach, you could do (with zsh) something like:

```
zmodload zsh/system
tail -f -- $daemon_log_file |
  for file in file{1..5}; do
    cp -- $file $daemon_dir || exit
    while sysread -t 60 -o 1; do
      continue
    done
  done
```

Comment: btw, what's default time that inotifywait waits before quitting?

Comment: @Sollosa, there's no timeout by default. It returns as soon as there's an event matching the criteria. You can specify one with `-t` though. See the man page.