# Split large file in realtime whilst it is still being written to

Tags: command-line, split

I've got a program that will be generating 4 large binary files (400GB+ each) that I need to upload to AWS S3 as quickly as possible.

I'd like to begin uploading before the files are completely written; I'm toying with a few approaches and one that I feel may be viable is using `split`, but my implementation has a lot of room for improvement and I'm wondering if anyone has more appropriate techniques:

By piping `tail -f` of the output file into `split` I can split the file successfully, but need to kill the `tail` process once the file completes and that just seems sub-optimal. This splits the file into 1MB chunks (small, for testing):

```bash
tail -f -n +0 file1.bin | split -d -a 5 -b 1M - file1.bin_split_
```

Can someone suggest a better solution to splitting a file in realtime? I am looking for a command-line solution; my shell is Bash.

Comment: Assuming you are on Linux, I suppose that in a shell script or a `sh -c` you can place that pipeline in background and then run something like `fsnotifywait -e close_write file1.bin && trap : TERM && kill 0`

Comment: @LL3,  are you sure it is `kill 0`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes, in a script (or `sh -c`) the backgrounded pipeline gets the same process-group as the script itself, so `kill 0` (which sends SIGTERM to the script's own entire process-group) kills the pipeline too. Though I'm not sure how `split` would react.

Comment: can you modify the program that writes the file? Because this sounds like you don't want to split and upload finished file, you just want to directly stream to S3. What's the write speed

Comment: @MarcusMüller unfortunately it's DB backups and I really need to retain the originals in place; I could do interesting things with named pipes but that's not really ideal. I only have maximum throughput on the disks for the first 50% of the backup (1000MB/s) so looking to use the spare throughput on upload.

Comment: @LL3 excellent, thanks. Needed to kill the tail before the split to ensure the buffer flushes (unless there is some other way) but with a little process substitution I can capture that, and then have the trap call a function to trigger a kill on the tail, wait till it is dead, and then kill the script. seems to work: 

tail -f -n +0 file1.bin  > >(split -d -a 5 -b 1M - file1.bin_split_) & ;

tailpid=$!

Comment: Similar: [bash looping over files while tailing logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/707522)

Comment: Why do you need to split the files into chunks?  Can't you create your backup files to `stdout` and use `tee`?  Or use `rsync`?  `rsync` can do incremental transfers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input folks; lots of good suggestions and questions have allowed me to come up with a workable solution for the handful of times I need to use this.

To answer a bunch of questions though: it's for a migration to a different AWS account, including restoring the DB; I'm constrained by security and architecture and want to make the best use of the tools at my disposal rather than putting time and effort into changes that may have negligible benefits; I *can* do it the slow way, carrying out each step sequentially, but there are benefits to getting this done quicker; it's AWS so I can spec/add whatever disks I decide; I don't want to stream it directly in case there is an interruption of some sort (i.e. I really need to put the data onto local EBS as a plan-B); is rsync not relatively slow?; and finally, named pipes are an option but then i'd need to rename the output files - i'm not convinced they would give me a huge benefit.

Anyway, the solution i've come up with is as follows:

**source:** backup from EBS volume1 --> EBS volume2; split 20GB chunks from EBS volume2 --> EBS volume3; upload chunks to S3 from EBS volume3

**target**: download chunks from S3 to stdout, appending on to target file(s) in EBS volume2; restore from EBS volume2 into EBS volume1

Code (apologies this is hacked together, but it will be thrown away soon):

**tails3.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#tails3.sh 
#takes two parameters: file to tail/split, and location to upload it to 
#splits the file to /tmpbackup/ into 20GB chunks. 
#waits while the chunks are still growing 
#sends the final (less than 20GB) chunk on the basis that the tail -f has completed

#i.e. for splitting 3 files simultaneously
#for file in <backup_filename>.00[1-3]; do bash -c "./tails3.sh $file s3://my-bucket/parts/ > /dev/null &"; done
# $1=filename
# $2=bucket/location


set -o pipefail

LOGFILE=$1.log


timestamp() { date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"; }

function log {
    printf "%s - %s\n" "$(timestamp)" "${*}"
    printf "%s - %s\n" "$(timestamp)" "${*}" >> "${LOGFILE}"
}

function closeoff {
  while kill -0 $tailpid 2>/dev/null; do
    kill $tailpid 2>/dev/null
    sleep 1
    log "slept waiting to kill"
  done
}

tail -f -n +0 $1  > >(split -d -a 5 -b 20G - /tmpbackup/$1_splitting_) &

tailpid=$!

inotifywait -e close_write $1 && trap : TERM && closeoff &

log "Starting looking for uploads in 5 seconds"
sleep 5


FINISHED=false
PARTSIZE=21474836480
FILEPREVSIZE=0

until $FINISHED; 
do 
    FILETOTRANSFER=$(ls -1a /tmpbackup/${1}_splitting_* | head -n 1)
    RC=$?
    kill -0 $tailpid >/dev/null 
    STILLRUNNING=$?
    log "RC: ${RC}; Still running: ${STILLRUNNING}"
    if [[ $RC > 0 ]]; then 
        if [[ ${STILLRUNNING} == 0 ]]; then 
            log "tail still running, will try again in 20 seconds"
            sleep 20
        else 
            log "no more files found, tail finished, quitting"
            FINISHED=true
        fi
    else 
        log "File to transfer: ${FILETOTRANSFER}, RC is ${RC}"
        FILEPART=${FILETOTRANSFER: -5}
        FILESIZE=$(stat --format=%s ${FILETOTRANSFER})
        log "on part ${FILEPART} with current size '${FILESIZE}', prev size '${FILEPREVSIZE}'"


        if [[ ${FILESIZE} == ${PARTSIZE} ]] || ([[ ${STILLRUNNING} > 0 ]] && [[ ${FILESIZE} == ${FILEPREVSIZE} ]]); then
            log "filesize: ${FILESIZE} == ${PARTSIZE}'; STILLRUNNING: ${STILLRUNNING}; prev size '${FILEPREVSIZE}'"
            log "Going to mv file ${FILETOTRANSFER} to _uploading_${FILEPART}"
            mv ${FILETOTRANSFER} /tmpbackup/${1}_uploading_${FILEPART}
            log "Going to upload /tmpbackup/${1}_uploading_${FILEPART}"
            aws s3 cp /tmpbackup/${1}_uploading_${FILEPART} ${2}${1}_uploaded_${FILEPART}
            mv /tmpbackup/${1}_uploading_${FILEPART} /tmpbackup/${1}_uploaded_${FILEPART}
            log "aws s3 upload finished" 
        else
            log "Sleeping 30"
            sleep 30
        fi
        FILEPREVSIZE=${FILESIZE}

    fi 

done 

log "Finished"
```

and
**s3join.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#s3join.sh 

#takes two parameters: source filename, plus bucket location 
#i.e. for a 3 part backup: 
#`for i in 001 002 003; do bash -c "./s3join.sh <backup_filename>.$i s3://my-bucket/parts/ > /dev/null &"; done `
#once all files are downloaded into the original, delete the $FILENAME.downloading file to cleanly exit
#you can tell when the generated file matches the size of the original file from the source server 
# $1 = target filename
# $2 = bucket/path

set -o pipefail

FILENAME=$1
BUCKET=$2
LOGFILE=${FILENAME}.log

timestamp() { date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"; }

function die {
    log ${*}
    exit 1
}

function log {
    printf "%s - %s\n" "$(timestamp)" "${*}"
    printf "%s - %s\n" "$(timestamp)" "${*}" >> "${LOGFILE}"
}

touch ${FILENAME}.downloading
i=0 

while [ -f ${FILENAME}.downloading ]; do 
    part=$(printf "%05d" $i)
    log "Looking for ${BUCKET}${FILENAME}_uploading_${part}"
    FILEDETAILS=$(aws s3 ls --summarize ${BUCKET}${FILENAME}_uploaded_${part})
    RC=$?
    if [[ ${RC} = 0 ]]; then 
        log "RC was ${RC} so file is in s3; output was ${FILEDETAILS}; downloading"
        aws s3 cp ${BUCKET}${FILENAME}_uploaded_${part} - >> ${FILENAME}
        ((i=i+1))
    else 
        log "could not find file, sleeping for 30 seconds. remove ${FILENAME}.downloading to quit"
        sleep 30
    fi
done
```

Using the above, I start my backup, then immediately trigger `tails3.sh` with the backup filenames that are being generated. This splits those files to a different volume. When the split parts get to 20GB (hardcoded) they start uploading to s3. This repeats until all files are uploaded and the `tail -f` of the backup file is terminated.

Shortly after this begins, on the target server I trigger `s3join.sh` using the backup filenames being generated on source. This process then polls s3 periodically, downloading any 'parts' that it finds and appending them to backup files. This keeps going until I tell it to stop (by deleting .downloading) as I was too lazy to set it to stop after downloading any file that isn't exactly 20GB...

And, for good measure, as soon as the first set of parts is appended into the target backup file, I can begin the DB restore, because restore is the slowest part of the process, backup the next slowest, and s3 upload/download is the fastest. i.e. backup at ~500MB/s; upload/download at up to ~700MB/s; restore at ~400MB/s.

Test of the process today on a dev environment which should have been (1hr backup + 20 mins upload + 20 mins download + 1hr restore = 2hr 40m) did the source to target restore in about 1hr 20m.

One final thing to note - I get the impression that there is some caching on `tail -f` for the `aws s3 cp` as Read MB/s doesn't seem to be getting hit as hard as it should.

Comment: caution with this answer though - if the `tail -f` falls behind the file being generated, it will stop and end up sending a partial file

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet bellow might be saved into file and launched as

```
./script.sh <PATH_TO_FILE_FOR_SPLITTING>
```

This script will continually check the size of file and split that file into 1M parts via dd utility. The termination of script is implemented via continual checking for specific file existence (/tmp/.finish in that case) as soon as the file occur the script will finish it self.

Now, you can create second script leveraging inotify that will create that file in case close_write event occur.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

path_to_file="${1}"
splitted=0
STREAM_FINISHED="/tmp/.finish"

while true ; do

  old_size="${actual_size:-0}"
  _actual_size="$(du "${path_to_file}")"
  actual_size="${_actual_size%$path_to_file}"
  actual_size_old_size_diff=$((actual_size-old_size))

  all_parts_size=$((splitted*1024))

  parts_whole_difference=$((actual_size-all_parts_size))

  part_written=0
  if [ "${actual_size_old_size_diff}" -ge 1024 ] || [ "${parts_whole_difference}" -ge 1024 ] ; then

      dd if="${path_to_file}" of="${splitted}".part iflag=skip_bytes skip=$((1048576*splitted)) bs=1048576 count=1

      echo "Part has been written"

      splitted=$((splitted+1))
      part_written=1

  fi

  if [ -f "${STREAM_FINISHED}" ] ; then

    echo "Finishing. Ensure part == whole"

    case "${parts_whole_difference}" in
      0)
        break
      ;;
      *)
        if [ "${part_written}" -eq 0 ] ; then

          echo "Creating last part"

          dd if="${path_to_file}" of="${splitted}".part iflag=skip_bytes skip=$((1048576*splitted))
          break
        fi
      ;;
    esac
  fi
done
```

Comment: interesting. i'd considered that but wasn't sure of the potential read impact of 'dd skip'. to be fair, i've not considered the read impact of 'tail -f' either...

Comment: Good point. From performance point of view I'd guess tail is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't quite make it clear why you believe you need to split the file.  Given that your stated objective is to transfer the file as quickly as possible, and to be able to begin the transfer even before the writing is complete, it seems all you need is a file transfer tool that can deal with the transfer of a file whose size is actively increasing during the transfer.

The stalwart `rsync` utility is likely all you need, but it was difficult for me to construct a test case to conclusively prove as much.  So what follows is something of a "suspenders-and-a-belt" approach.  Not only does `rsync` perform checks during the file transfer to see if the source file is being appended to during the transfer, the script logic itself also loops anytime it detects that the `stat` output of the file(s) is different upon exit from `rsync` than it was when `rsync` started.

A second bit of redundancy is that the script uses the `mtree` utility to perform a `sha256` checksum validation of the transferred files.  `rsync` ostensibly does this also, although it's validation is somewhat less than explicit.  Given that we're relying heavily on the `--append` feature of `rsync`, I felt that the highest level of confidence in the transfer would result from validating the files by a means independent of the transfer mechanism itself.  In the presumably rare case when `mtree` finds an anomaly,
it's `rsync` to the rescue again, for one final checksum-enabled pass to re-transfer the file(s) that fail the checksum.  The checksumming will take time, but still, I believe this method will be a robust solution for your needs.

Some points to consider:

1. It takes time to split the files before transfer.  You'll likely be reading and writing from the same disk, at the same time that the backup job itself is running.  This competition for disk bandwidth will slow down both the backup job itself and the unnecessary splitting process.
2. The file-splitting duplicates disk space.  Even if that's not a concern now, it may be in the future, or for other readers who deploy this solution.
3. The file will have to be re-assembled at the remote end, which will again consume disk and time.
4. It seems intuitive that the fastest way to begin transferring the files is to start sending it out the network interface as soon as possible.  The splitting is an unnecessary delay, and this method begins transfer almost immediately upon startup.

If you don't already, you should create an `ssh` key that will permit you to securely and conveniently log in to your AWS instance from the machine that is creating the dumps.  Once that is in place, consider the following `bash` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Several large binary files are being generated in src_dir.  They need to
# to be uploaded to a remote host as quickly as possible, even while they're
# still being written.

# This solution doesn't care how many files there are, all files in src_dir
# get copied to dst_dir on dst_host.  Any pre-existing files in dst_dir are
# deleted.

src_dir='where/my/files/are'        # slash will be appended
dst_dir='my/AWS/path'               # slash will be appended
dst_host='my.aws.example.com'       # remote host FQDN only

# what rsync syntax shall we use for incremental passes?
# --append is important.

rs_inc='rsync -av -P --append --delete'

# what rsync syntax shall we use for absolute verification (checksum) passes?

rs_chk='rsync -av -c --delete'

# to begin, we must have an empty $dst_dir on $dst_host:

ssh $dst_host rm -vf "$dst_dir"'/*'

# and we need some files to transfer in src_dir

if ! stat $src_dir/* > /dev/null 2>&1
then
        printf 'no files found in %s\n' "$src_dir"
        exit 1
fi

# begin with blank (undefined) src file status

src_stat=

printf 'beginning transfer ...\n'

# loop while the current src file status differs from src_stat

while [[ "$(stat $src_dir/*)" != "$src_stat" ]]
do

        # Before we start rsync, record the src_dir state.

        src_stat="$(stat $src_dir/*)"

        # Then do an incremental rsync of src_dir to dst_host:dst_dir

        $rs_inc "$src_dir"/ $dst_host:"$dst_dir"/

        # Now loop back and check stat again.  If the files have changed
        # while rsync was running, then we'll need to loop again with 
        # another incremental transfer.

done

# Now use mtree(8) to ensure that the src and dst paths contain the same
# files.

printf 'verifying files ...\n'
# It's handy to pause here when testing:
#read -p 'Press Enter ... '

if mtree -ck sha256digest,size,time -p "$src_dir" | ssh $dst_host mtree -p "$dst_dir"
then
        printf 'files in local path %s and remote path %s:%s pass SHA256 test\n' \
                "$src_dir" $dst_host "$dst_dir"
else
        printf 'one or more files in local path %s and remote path %s:%s fail SHA256 test\n' \
                "$src_dir" $dst_host "$dst_dir"
        printf 're-transfering...\n'
        $rs_chk "$src_dir"/* $dst_host:"$dst_dir"/
fi
```

Comment: thanks; I want to keep a local copy in case the upload fails (yeah, not likely, but covering my arse); how performant is rsync? ; reassembling by downloading from s3 stdout doesn't really seem to have an overhead

Comment: @AlistairSwanson I think many would rate rsync as best-in-class.  But use cases vary, so you may want to test and time both methods, including some tests where you deliberately attempt to induce some errors or anomalous situations, to contrast both the speed and the reliability of the various methods at your disposal.